# ajax laravel delete button

Tags: jquery, laravel

so i want to delete an image using ajax request. the image id is being passed to the function but i get an error when i try to destroy the same image. here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
               var url = "/delete";
                 $('.delete').click(function(){
                    var id = $(this).val();
                  //  alert(id);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        data: { id: 1 },
                        url: url + '/' + id,

                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);

                           // $("#task" + id).remove();
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            console.log('Error:', data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

the route

```
    Route::get('/delete/{id?}',function(Request $request,$id){ 
 if(Request::ajax())
 {
    $delete = File::destroy($id);
  return $delete ; 
} });
```

i get a javascript Error: Object { readyState:4 getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.... please help me solve this to identify the problem

Comment: What error you get? PHP error or JS error? Add more information

Comment: as xdevnull said we need the error details , and also notice that you are passing an id .. and your file is an image , jpg or whatever...

Comment: plase take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token you need to include a meta tag in html and set ajax headers

Comment: so this is the error av gotten from the log : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::ajax()

Comment: about the file, i just want to delete the row in  the database without really removing the file from the uploads folder

Comment: @DominicMuse check my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are many different reasons that will cause that error,

But probably `Request::ajax()` could be reason for that. Instead use

```
Route::get('/delete/{id}', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $id) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        return $id;
    }
});
```

**Update**: OP had different problems,

- calling static `ajax()` on Request facade that doesn't not
  exists.
- Method Type in Ajax was `POST` instead of `GET`
- PHP Syntax error in laravel project

Comment: Its not neccessarily a file that i want to delete.. even just a database record. the problem is when i pass the id its being displayed in the console without issues but when i add the deleting part, its displays the error

Comment: @DominicMuse Can you come the code above. and test it? add console.log(data) in the success function.

Comment: So. id display But can you open the log error, you probably missing "namespacing" can you show me example of deleting record that cause problem?

Comment: @ xdevnull yes and this is what i get: 17:02:34.886 Error: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }1 /:34:33

Comment: @DominicMuse Above that do you get any error, Like ```error 500``` ? If you don't mind paste the laravel.log in any paste service and give me link

Comment: F:\Projects\NEW\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 F:\Projects\NEW\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 F:\Projects\NEW\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 F:\Projects\NEW\server.php(21): require_once('F:\\Projects\\NEW...')
#23 {main}

Comment: xdevnull  i have pasted the last lines of the log file

Comment: That doesn't help. i need full file. use ```http://pastebin.com/``` or ```gist.github.com``` paste it there. and give me link.

Comment: or just to help, you could please write me a sample ajax delete request that has worked with you, coz most of what i get from my research just leads me to errors.Please, i rilly need to know

Comment: Okay, I'll update my answer with simple little example.

Comment: If you don't mind can you paste ```routes.php``` and the view for ```button``` ? and the ajax again?

Comment: I will really appreciate

Comment: what about deleting a form entry for instance a table car.. has the columns id, model type, manufacture_year. so iwant delete one of the row values entered using ajax

Comment: the routes and view are on the thread above, thats for the one about deleteting the files

Comment: @DominicMuse I've updated my answer in the route, check it. I assume you have Car model.

Comment: xdevnull ok let me implement it and see what i get

Comment: Apparently am still getting the same error, and i think it comes about in the function when am deleting... Has it worked for you on your end???? let me copy paste the error

Comment: @ xdevnull 18:01:31.464 Error: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }1 /:34:33

Comment: This question will lead to a long discussion. Can you play enter Laravel Support channel and i'll help you there. and we will update the question afterwards. http://laravel.io/chat my nickname: xdevnull

Comment: the gist link https://gist.github.com/dominicmuse/c2e7e0e62b23818b817f55affe7a1014